# Do single-sided radiators exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

Every single-sided antenna I have looked basically radiates in all directions but has some type of material to reflect the radiated wave to create nulls.

I'm wondering if it's possible to construct a radiator which is truly single sided? Ex a horn-antenna but which doesn't achieve directivity by reflection or cancelation?

My assumption is no since a moving electron radiates in all directions but I wanted to check.

Comment: what do you mean by a "single-sided" antenna?

Comment: I mean something which radiates directionally without either beamforming or using a reflector of some type.

Comment: Use the momentum conservation law, Luke!

Comment: Every radiator has a finite extent (aperture) thus all emissions suffer from diffraction, one cannot have emission into a singe direction not even with laser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they actually exists in order to achieve a single directional emissions one have to use *stimulated emission*. This is the primary principle that gives the lasers it's direction which are emitting EM radiation in a particular direction, if you are looking for microwaves you should look for Masers which works on similar concepts but in microwave regions,